# I can't get my "event.preventDefault" to work when submitting a form through button in overlay

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, http, post, flask

As the title says, I can't get my `event.preventDefault` to work on a submit POST request of my form. 
Using standard js, flask, css, and html.
ASFAIK there are no errors anywhere.
If I can just have the overlay stay where it is and still send the post back to flask that would help me a tons!! Thank you in advance.
Here are my codes...

Flask

```
defaultSettings = {'key': 'value'}

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', defaultSettings=defaultSettings)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="settings" onclick="openSettings()">
        <p>Settings</p>
        <img src="/static/menu-icon.png" alt="settings">
    </div>
    <div id="settingsID" class="SettingsMenu">
        <div class="saved" id="saved">
            <p id="saveText">saved!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeSettings()">&times;</a>
        <div class="SettingsMenu_content" id="SettingsMenu_content">
            <form method='POST' id="settingsForm">
            <div class="menu_div">
                <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ defaultSettings['key'] }}">
            <div class="configuration">
                <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="handleForm()" id="settings_submit">
                <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="closeSettings()">
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript (the problem part!)

```
"use strict";

function openSettings() {
  document.getElementById('settingsID').style.width = "100%";
}

function closeSettings() {
  document.getElementById('settingsID').style.width = "0%";
}

function handleForm() {
    document.getElementById('settingsForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

css (wrote as little as possible but don't know if it's even relevant...)

```
html {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #B0BEC5;
    color: #546E7A;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

.settings {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 64px;
    right: 20px;
    margin: 15px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.SettingsMenu {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
    //background-color: rgba(26,32,38, 0.7);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.SettingsMenu_content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 30px 15% auto 25%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.SettingsMenu a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.SettingsMenu .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="handleForm(event)" id="settings_submit">`

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="handleForm()" id="settings_submit">
```

Change the `handleForm` to , ypu dont need the `submit` again inside the `handleForm` function

```
function handleForm(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    //rest of the code
}
```